# bind param array php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have written a code to bind with an array.
The code i have now is:

```
$user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];

$db = new mysqli("localhost", "username", "password", "database");

$stmt = $db -> prepare("SELECT aps FROM `scu_user-data` WHERE id=? LIMIT 1");
$stmt->bind_param('i', $user_id);
$stmt->execute();
$res = $stmt->get_result();

while ($row = $res->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
  if ($res[0] == 0){
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
    echo 'window.location = "http://localhost/system/aps.php"';
    echo '</script>';
  } else {
    echo " ";
  }
}

$stmt->close();
```

i get an errror message saying:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array

Comment: Improved formatting.

Answer (score 1):

The error is here:

```
if ($res[0] == 0)
```

$res is a result set object. Presumably you meant to use the variable $row you used on the previous line:

```
if ($row['aps'] == 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

By using the `MYSQLI_ASSOC` constant your code will behave identically to the `mysqli_fetch_assoc()`, while `MYSQLI_NUM` will behave identically to the `mysqli_fetch_row()` function, which is the one I think you want.

Try using [`MYSQLI_NUM`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php).

Also, make sure you check to see whether the query has run successfully before attempting to extract rows from it, change `$res = $stmt->get_result();` to:

```
if(!$res = $stmt->get_result()){
    die($db->error);
}
```

Comment: Maybe the query didn't run successfully?